# How to set function arguments from data frame using purrr::pmap without writing all col names?

Tags: r, function, purrr

I have this data frame and function.

```
df <- tibble(
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c",
  d = "d",
  e = "e",
  f = "f",
  g = "g"
)

pmap(df, function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
    
    var_1 <- paste0(a, b)

    var_2 <- c + d + e

    var_3 <- f/g

   tibble(
   a = var_1
   b = var_2
   c = var_3
)
    
  })
```

The function works as expected. Since the col names could be more than seven I don't want to have to write all col names inside `function()`. What could be done?

Desired similar code:

```
pmap(df, function(names(df)) {
  
    var_1 <- paste0(a, b)

    var_2 <- c + d + e

    var_3 <- f/g

   tibble(
   a = var_1
   b = var_2
   c = var_3
)
  
})
```

Comment: `purrr::pmap(df, paste0)`? Base R: `do.call(paste0, df)`.

Comment: The `paste0` is just an example, it's more complex. I do need to get col names inside `function()`

Comment: You can combined it with any select helpers such as `pmap(select(df, a:g), paste0)`.

Comment: That would work if I truly use `paste0` but this is not the real case. See above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, I prefer `with(list(...), #stuff here )`.

Building on stefan's working solution:

```
pmap(df,~with(list(...),{var_1 <- paste0(a, b);
                        var_2 <- c + d + e;
                        var_3 <- f/g;
                        tibble(a = var_1, b = var_2, c = var_3)}))
#[[1]]
## A tibble: 1 × 3
#  a         b     c
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ab        6   0.8
```

Comment: What would yo do in a `mutate` context? and you wanna create new column with the `pmap` output in the new column

Comment: In a mutate context you don't have that problem, because the variables are already accessible by their symbols. You can always use `rowwise()` if your operations can't be vectorized.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is, you don't wanna write the col names again. Like this (at least it's the way I know.
`df %>% mutate(union = pmap(list(a, b, c, d, e, f, g), function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g){#stuff})`

Comment: You can use `df %>% mutate(union = pmap(dplyr::cur_data(), ~ with(list(...), #stuff))`

Comment: Hi, @Ian Campbell, sorry for bothering you again. Would you know a way when inside a ~with (list(...), X), being X the body of the function, in X to get variables without explicitly putting them. Normally I would do this: `any(e > c, e > d, e > f, e > g)` to get TRUE, but if I have many variables I would be tedious to put all variables, like this `any(e > c, e > d, e > f, e > g, e > h, e > i, e > j, e > k, e > l, etc)`

Answer (score 4):

Using `...`, `list2env` and `rlang::current_env` you could do:

Note: I slightly changed your example data so that c to g are numerics.

```r
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble(
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = 1,
  d = 2,
  e = 3,
  f = 4,
  g = 5
)

pmap(df, function(...) {
  list2env(list(...), envir = rlang::current_env())
  
  var_1 <- paste0(a, b)
  
  var_2 <- c + d + e
  
  var_3 <- f/g
  
  tibble(
    a = var_1,
    b = var_2,
    c = var_3
  )
})
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   a         b     c
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ab        6   0.8
```